# How to get a docker log file from a container which will exit after start?

Tags: docker

I have a container, it will exit caused by core dumped. However I want to get a log from container path `/opt/big/err.log`

If I start the container, it will core dumped and exit quickly.

And I tried to mount the directory using `docker run -v $(pwd)/log:/opt/big` but if I add this mounting there is error

`Docker Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed`

Is there any way to get this log file out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to copy using:

```
docker cp CONTAINER_NAME:/opt/big $(pwd)/log
```

Comment: it works! I have tried `docker cp NAME:/opt/big/* ./log` before but it did not work